# java constructor in super classes

Tags: java

The following code is a testing program. Why i can't use A(int a), in this program?

```
public class A {
    int a;
    void meth(int b) {
        a+=b;
    }
    A(int a) {
        this.a=a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int a;
    void meh2(int b) {
        a+=b;
    }
}
```

why can't pass parameter to constructor? What the reasons? Netbeans error message:

constructor A in class tma1.A cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Why can't you? Doesn't look like you're even trying...

Comment: The devolution of "method":  `method` -> `meth` -> `meh2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class B, you need constructor. If you mean that you can't call A from B, that's just because you're extending class A, so you need to use super, which refer to the superclass. For example B could be:

```
    class B extends A {
    B(int a) {
//You can put additional code here

// This calls the constructor of A
        super(a);

//You can put additional code here
    }
    int a;
    void meh2(int b) {
        a+=b;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you need to assign something to the variable a in class B, if you're not omitting something in code

Comment: thanks,  but why remove int a in constructor in class A, the program will be ok?

Comment: Because Java creates implicitly a default constructor, which is like "classname()". So, if you give some parameter to constructor of A, the default constructor doesn't match with it and needs you to specify explicitly one.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a class has a defined constructor, it automatically has a no-arg constructor that merely calls `super()`.

The complaint from your compiler seems to be: "your no-arg constructor [that you can't see] is calling up to a parent no-arg constructor that doesn't exist."

Class `A` doesn't have a no-arg constructor because there's another one defined (so java doesn't have to create one).